# preg_replace_callback with PHP_EOL does not work on Linux

Tags: php, linux, line-breaks

I have a PHP code with process users input form html form and should remove PHP_EOL signs from the code. If I test it on my local Win 10 machine it works well. But As it is on production Linux server it does not. the code look like:

````
$text = preg_replace_callback('/```([^`]+)```/', function($m) {
    return '<pre class="prettyprint custom"><code>' . trim($m[1], PHP_EOL) . '</code></pre>';
}, $text);
````

I am not sure, but I think the reason is that the input comes from my Window browser to Linux. Am I right or not?

Answer (score 0):

You must trim both endline character. Linux `\n` and Windows `\r\n`. Instead of use `PHP_EOL` wich represent only the newline character on the current system, you can use

```php
trim($m[1],"\r\n")
```

Comment: Warning: trim() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given ! the first argument is enough.

Comment: argh ... my mistake... it's updated, thx.